# disappear element in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
classes = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'K', 'L'], ['C', 'E', 'D', 'H', 'K', 'L'], ['E', 'D', 'F', 'K', 'L'], ['D', 'G', 'H'], ['F', 'K'], ['G', 'F'], ['H', 'L'], ['K', 'H', 'L'], ['L']]

        
def get_parents(child,classes): 
    for element in classes:
        if element[0] == child:  
            parents_list = element
            parents_list.remove(child)
            return parents_list   
        
        
def check(parent, lst):
    for each_element in lst:
        if parent in each_element:
            return 'Yes'
    return 'No'

def prove(lst,parent):
    if parent in lst:
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return 'No'


print (prove(get_parents('D',classes.copy()),'K'))

print(classes)
print (get_parents('D',classes))

print (check('A',classes))
```

Why when I run this code, my func get_parents() delete **'D'** from list *'classes'* **[D,G,H]**? I guess, that `parents_list.remove(child)` deleting copied element in namespace def that i put in `parents_list`, but it changed global data without direct command.

Why this f*cking python so lazy, that can't dedicate some memory to new object, but  just linked my var to data in list?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `get_parents` function, you are referencing the `element`. Which is still linked to your `classes` collection. By creating a copy you remove the reference. So the fix to your problem is `parents_list = element.copy()`.

More information about the copy statement can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

*[btw, shadowing variable names is probably not the best idea and cause confusing results]*